# Invalidate a default session - NSURLSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

I'm using default NSURLSessions in my application. I would like to know,

1. Is it possible to invalidate a default session and whats the appropriate time to invalidate during the app life cycle?
2. When a session is invalidated, are the credentials for the session removed from the NSURLCredentialStorage or is there any other way of doing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Invalidate it when you know that you won't want to add any new requests to it, and when you either don't have any outstanding requests in that session or don't care about the results of those requests.

Without knowing what your app does, there's no way for us to know when that might be.  If you're implementing a browser, for example, you might create a session for each tab, and invalidate the session when the user closes the tab, optionally canceling any outstanding requests.

Credentials can be per-session or permanent.  By default, I think it lasts for the duration of the app session, which means that it lasts until the app is closed.  If you want it to be per-URL-session, IIRC, you need to create your own credential storage object, and specify that the URL session should use that object.  Then, when the URL session goes away, so does the object.  Depending on what you're doing, you might need to create your own subclass that looks things up in the shared credential cache first, but always stores them only in itself.